# Can I create tables with different names at a time into procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I wrote

```
create or replace procedure crab
    (no in number, name in varchar2, marks in number)
as
begin
    create table customer (no number(6),name varchar2 (12),marks number (3));
end;
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the procedure parameters and the columns in the table? What do you expect to get?

Comment: And also can anybody tell me that how to create 5 tables at a time in plsql using cursor or procedures

Comment: Ya I'm trying to create a table with those columns

Comment: Here would perfectly fit Ryan Reynolds "but why" meme. Implementing DDL statements with procedures is considered as "bad practice" - you should avoid this approach. If you need some temporary data structure at run time - oracle provides vast options of PL/SQL collection types.

Comment: Try [`execute immediate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.html) (with the usual warnings about dynamic code).

Comment: Sir can you explain clearly about creation of tables in procedures

Comment: What do you want to happen the second time you call the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Although you *can* do that, you most probably should *not* do it. Why would you? That's what comments under your question suggest. In Oracle, you usually don't create tables *dynamically* unless there's a really good reason to do it. What is your reason?

Anyway, here's an example which shows *how* to do it.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure crab as
  2  begin
  3    execute immediate 'create table tab1 (no number(6), name varchar2(12))';
  4    execute immediate 'create table tab2 (no number(6), name varchar2(12))';
  5    -- etc.
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  2    crab;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from tab where tname in ('TAB1', 'TAB2');

TNAME                          TABTYPE  CLUSTERID
------------------------------ ------- ----------
TAB1                           TABLE
TAB2                           TABLE

SQL>
```

Comment: This question was actually raised by an interviewer. So, I just want to know the answer. Anyway tq so much

Comment: Well, this *is* the answer - dynamic SQL. So, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do a DDL from within a procedure, you need dynamic SQL.

For example:

```
...
Begin
  execute immediate 'Create table customer (no number(6),name varchar2(12),marks number(3))';
End;
```

This will create a table with column names and types as written in dynamic DDL, no matter the input parameters.

Comment: Tq so much.i got some knowledge From you